# Perfect matching in the Petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I have to prove that the Petersen graph has only one perfect match, I have one perfect match but I dont know how to prove formaly that it's unique.

Comment: A perfect matching is a matching wich matches all every vertex in a graph.

Answer (score 2):

The Petersen graph has six perfect matchings, not just one.

If you only found one, you probably found the one that's rotationally symmetric in the standard picture of the Petersen graph, with $5$-fold symmetry. There are five more (that are all rotations of the same pattern).

You can also look for matchings in the drawing of the Petersen graph with $3$-fold symmetry:

[image: Petersen graph]

Here, the six perfect matchings come in two families of three (where each family consists of three rotations of the same matching). Because it's impossible to have a rotationally symmetric perfect matching in this drawing (the central vertex can only be matched to *one* of the outside vertices) it's easy to see that the number of perfect matchings must be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: What is the vital difference between 1-factorisation and perfect matchings? I have seen that if a regular graph is 1-factorisable, then it should be of Class 1, that is edge-colorable with $\Delta$ colors, where $\Delta$ be the maximum degree. On the other hand, I have also seen that if an even order graph is hamiltonian, the graph is 1-factorisable, in this case, the graph is non-hamiltonian. But, you show perfect matchings. Am I missing something?

Comment: A perfect matching is a single 1-factor; a 1-factorization is a partition into 1-factors