# What are all possible combinations of 5 numbers in a pentagram?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In a pentagram, the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 should be inserted. (See image)

How many combinations are there, if on the 5 straight lines (with 4 circles each), no number can occur more than once ?

[image: 1]

I have tried to rotate figure 2, in doing so I come up with 5 possibilities. But it is also possible to use the numbers several times. I have tried to recognize a pattern, but unfortunately I have not found one.

Does anyone have an idea or an approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V$ is the set of nodes from your figure and $\{v,w\}\in E$ if and only if $v$ and $w$ don't share a line in the above diagram (here, a line is one of the lines of length 4 that you described). Then $G$ is cubic. In fact, $G$ is a labeled Petersen-Graph. Now note that any valid distribution of the numbers $1$ to $5$ corresponds to a perfect matching in $G$ and vice versa, i.e. we only need to count the distinct perfect matchings in $G$ and then label the edges in those matchings. The latter can always be done in $5!$ ways, since every number must appear exactly two times (On one match; can you see why?). On paper, it is now relatively straightforward to list all perfect matchings of $G$ (there are 6 total, refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2551863/884395). Altogether this yields $6 \cdot 5! = 6!$ possible answers.

Comment: I have never heard of the Petersen-Graph. Thank you that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We can verify @SimonK's answer via enumeration. It is easy to see that no number can appear more than twice, so each number must appear exactly twice.

In R:

```
library(Rfast) # for the rowMaxs and rowTabulate functions

# get every distinct permutation of rep(1:5, 2)
m <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(5, 10, FALSE, rep(2, 5))

# define the five lines in the pentagram (1:5 = inside pentagon,
# 6:10 = outside points; 6 adjacent to 1-2, 7 adjacent to 2-3, etc.)
lns <- matrix(
  c(
    1, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    2, 5, 3, 4, 5,
    7, 6, 6, 7, 8,
    10,9, 8, 9, 10
  ), 4, 5, 1
)

# remove permutations that have a line with a number appearing more than once
for (i in 1:5) m <- m[rowMaxs(rowTabulate(m[,lns[,i]], 5L)*1, TRUE) == 1L,]

# answer:
nrow(m)
#> [1] 720

# SimonK's answer:
factorial(6)
#> [1] 720
```

Comment: It is a good idea to test this again as a program. Thank you.